# Send message for one user to multiple clients

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, server

I'm creating a TCP server using Qt. Clients can create user account with login and pass and log in. So, there may be a situation where one user account will be used by several clients (sockets). And if I need to send a message to some user, then I need to notify all clients(sockets) which are authorized as this user. But how can I implement this behaviour? Now I using next design.

I have `QMultiHash<int, MyClient*> clients` which contains id of user as key and socket as value:
When some client connects to the server I add it to the `clients`, and when some client disconnects I remove it from the `clients`. If I need to send a message to some user, then I get all sockets which are authorized as this user from `clients` and send message to each. Code sample:

```
//...

QMultiHash<int, MyClient*> clients;

//...

void MyServer::addNewClient(int id, MyClient *client){
    clients.insert(id, client);
}

void MyServer::removeClient(int id){
    clients.remove(id);
}

void MyServer::sendMessage(int recipientId, QString str){

    if (clients.contains(recipientId)){
        QList<MyClient*> values = clients.values(recipientId);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
            values.at(i)->pushMessage(str);
    }
}
```

**Is this a correct solution or I should to implement something another?**

Comment: Yes, if you have a list all your clients than yes. But what is Qlist<MyClient*>? MyClient* is QTcpSocket ?

Comment: @Taz742 almost yes: `MyClient` isn't inherited from `QTcpSocket`, but it has field `QTcpSocket`

Comment: I am also interested in the client when contacts to the server, after first connection do you disconnect from this server instantly?

Comment: @Taz742 no, socket expects further interaction between the client and the server. But why are you asking?

Comment: Because if the client is off, how does the server send a message?

Comment: Your question: Is this a correct solution or I should to implement something another? I can say yes, it is a correct solution.

Comment: @Taz742 understood :) Ok, thanks!